# Rendering PDF proofs with Java (via LaTex?)

Tags: java, latex, pdf-generation, pdflatex, proof

Currently I am working on a automated theorem prover in Java.

I would like to be able to render these proofs, as PDF.
Preferrably, this will go though something like LaTeX, using [proof.sty](http://www.phil.cam.ac.uk/teaching_staff/Smith/LaTeX/ndexamples/proofsty.html) or [qtree.sty](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/advice/latex/qtree/).
However, I've read that rendering LaTeX code from Java can be [a bit problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612260/library-to-convert-latex-to-png-in-java).

In Java, the proofs are represented by simple trees, inspired on the Haskell trees, as:

```
class Tree<A> {
  A       value;
  List<A> subForest;
}
```

Has anybody got any ideas on how to best do this?

On a related note (i.e. the all-else-fails solution) what are the best practices for calling a `pdflatex` executable from Java? (As for locating it, figuring out whether or not it exists, etc...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [jproc](http://code.google.com/p/jproc/) to run pdflatex. It let's you specify a timeout and takes care of processing stdout and stderr as well as interpreting the return code.
Make sure that you launch pdflatex with -interaction=batchmode parameter, so it doesn't stop at every error.
Furthermore I would recommend to use a templating engine like velocity or stringtemplate to produce the input for latex. 
Alternatively you might want to look at jlatexmath which aims at offering a java api to latex formulas.